# Drawing a surface using an Excel file

Tags: plotting, data, excel, matlab

I’m totally new to Mathlab. I have the following ‘grid data’ to be read from ‘Office Excel’ that I need them to be drawn as a surface in the Mathematica or Mathlab.

[image: [[DATA PICTURE]]]

I’ve done this with the ‘Surface’ application; but, I’m not satisfied with the output. I do love the way the ‘Mathlab’ or the ‘Mathemaica’ draw these things with their unique and gorgeous outputs.

[image: [[SURFER OUTPUT]]]

I can get a ‘.grd’ file from an ‘.xlsx’ (Excel) using the ‘Surface’ application to do the 3D drawings; but, I do want them to be drawn using ‘Mathlab’ or ‘Mathematica’; how to do that?

My all data in the ‘.xlsx’ file with the form `{x, y, z}`:

```
{0, -42, 9.154647E+13}, {9.09327, -36.75, 9.614679E+13}, {18.18653, -31.5, 9.950809E+13}, {27.2798, -26.25, 9.617123E+13}, {36.37306, -21, 9.159174E+13}, {-9.09327, -36.75, 9.610033E+13}, {0, -31.5, 9.982879E+13}, {9.09327, -26.25, 1.066651E+14}, {18.18653, -21, 1.066760E+14}, {27.2798, -15.75, 9.985912E+13}, {36.37306, -10.5, 9.615046E+13}, {-18.18653, -31.5, 9.941883E+13}, {-9.09327, -26.25, 1.066308E+14}, {0, -21, 1.180334E+14}, {9.09327, -15.75, 1.226739E+14}, {18.18653, -10.5, 1.180546E+14}, {27.2798, -5.25, 1.066687E+14}, {36.37306, 0, 9.947475E+13}, {-27.2798, -26.25, 9.604409E+13}, {-18.18653, -21, 1.066111E+14}, {-9.09327, -15.75, 1.226429E+14}, {0, -10.5, 1.363291E+14}, {9.09327, -5.25, 1.363397E+14}, {18.18653, 0, 1.226722E+14}, {27.2798, 5.25, 1.066531E+14}, {36.37306, 10.5, 9.610285E+13}, {-36.37306, -21, 9.142813E+13}, {-27.2798, -15.75, 9.976877E+13}, {-18.18653, -10.5, 1.179963E+14}, {-9.09327, -5.25, 1.363113E+14}, {0, 0, 1.571756E+14}, {9.09327, 5.25, 1.363308E+14}, {18.18653, 10.5, 1.180302E+14}, {27.2798, 15.75, 9.980929E+13}, {36.37306, 21, 9.148295E+13}, {-36.37306, -10.5, 9.602540E+13}, {-27.2798, -5.25, 1.065873E+14}, {-18.18653, 0, 1.226169E+14}, {-9.09327, 5.25, 1.363036E+14}, {0, 10.5, 1.363138E+14}, {9.09327, 15.75, 1.226445E+14}, {18.18653, 21, 1.066221E+14}, {27.2798, 26.25, 9.605668E+13}, {-36.37306, 0, 9.935848E+13}, {-27.2798, 5.25, 1.065738E+14}, {-18.18653, 10.5, 1.179760E+14}, {-9.09327, 15.75, 1.226173E+14}, {0, 21, 1.179992E+14}, {9.09327, 26.25, 1.066114E+14}, {18.18653, 31.5, 9.939575E+13}, {-36.37306, 10.5, 9.598052E+13}, {-27.2798, 15.75, 9.972668E+13}, {-18.18653, 21, 1.065676E+14}, {-9.09327, 26.25, 1.065856E+14}, {0, 31.5, 9.977488E+13}, {9.09327, 36.75, 9.605066E+13}, {-36.37306, 21, 9.133061E+13}, {-27.2798, 26.25, 9.595305E+13}, {-18.18653, 31.5, 9.933475E+13}, {-9.09327, 36.75, 9.602483E+13}, {0, 42, 9.146442E+13}
```

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: I used `tri = delaunay(x,y);` `trisurf(tri,x,y,z)`, where `x`, `y` and `z` are my columns in the excel file, but the result is not what I want. and in Mathematica I used `ListPlot3D[data, Mesh -> None, InterpolationOrder -> 3]` command, where the data is my `x`, `y` and `z`. and the result is totally different!

Comment: This site is abouth Mathematica, not MATLAB - if you are not using Mathematica, this question will be closed. Please specify.

Comment: @YvesKlett I'm using both and in this site, I need Mathematica codes to achieve the same result as Surfer.

Comment: Please show us the `data`, in copyable form. Without knowing what the `data` is, it's hard to tell what's wrong.

Comment: @xzczd I just added the `data`, in a copyable form to my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your data is not properly imported: things like `9.614679E+13` are not valid number in *Mathematica*. Once again, without knowing how you imported the data, it's hard to tell what's wrong, so here I'll just fix the erroneous data:

```
dat = ToExpression@StringReplace[#, "E+" -> "*10^"] &@"{{0,-42,9.154647E+13},{9.09327,-36.75,9.614679E+13},{18.18653,-31.5,9.950809E+13},{27.2798,-26.25,9.617123E+13},{36.37306,-21,9.159174E+13},{-9.09327,-36.75,9.610033E+13},{0,-31.5,9.982879E+13},{9.09327,-26.25,1.066651E+14},{18.18653,-21,1.066760E+14},{27.2798,-15.75,9.985912E+13},{36.37306,-10.5,9.615046E+13},{-18.18653,-31.5,9.941883E+13},{-9.09327,-26.25,1.066308E+14},{0,-21,1.180334E+14},{9.09327,-15.75,1.226739E+14},{18.18653,-10.5,1.180546E+14},{27.2798,-5.25,1.066687E+14},{36.37306,0,9.947475E+13},{-27.2798,-26.25,9.604409E+13},{-18.18653,-21,1.066111E+14},{-9.09327,-15.75,1.226429E+14},{0,-10.5,1.363291E+14},{9.09327,-5.25,1.363397E+14},{18.18653,0,1.226722E+14},{27.2798,5.25,1.066531E+14},{36.37306,10.5,9.610285E+13},{-36.37306,-21,9.142813E+13},{-27.2798,-15.75,9.976877E+13},{-18.18653,-10.5,1.179963E+14},{-9.09327,-5.25,1.363113E+14},{0,0,1.571756E+14},{9.09327,5.25,1.363308E+14},{18.18653,10.5,1.180302E+14},{27.2798,15.75,9.980929E+13},{36.37306,21,9.148295E+13},{-36.37306,-10.5,9.602540E+13},{-27.2798,-5.25,1.065873E+14},{-18.18653,0,1.226169E+14},{-9.09327,5.25,1.363036E+14},{0,10.5,1.363138E+14},{9.09327,15.75,1.226445E+14},{18.18653,21,1.066221E+14},{27.2798,26.25,9.605668E+13},{-36.37306,0,9.935848E+13},{-27.2798,5.25,1.065738E+14},{-18.18653,10.5,1.179760E+14},{-9.09327,15.75,1.226173E+14},{0,21,1.179992E+14},{9.09327,26.25,1.066114E+14},{18.18653,31.5,9.939575E+13},{-36.37306,10.5,9.598052E+13},{-27.2798,15.75,9.972668E+13},{-18.18653,21,1.065676E+14},{-9.09327,26.25,1.065856E+14},{0,31.5,9.977488E+13},{9.09327,36.75,9.605066E+13},{-36.37306,21,9.133061E+13},{-27.2798,26.25,9.595305E+13},{-18.18653,31.5,9.933475E+13},{-9.09327,36.75,9.602483E+13},{0,42,9.146442E+13}}";

ListPlot3D@dat
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Wow, Thank you, and we can use `PlotLegends -> Automatic` option to get the same result with surfer, (maybe a more gorgeous output).